# How to best dynamically crop photos of documents in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, image-processing, sharp

I have a small web-app that processes photos of receipts.

I am wondering how to best modify these photos on my NodeJS server. I would like to be able to remove the background and center the image of the receipt on the server. Which tool would be best suited for this?

For example, going from Sample 1 to Sample 2.

[image: Sample 1 - Receipt with background]
[image: Sample 2 - Receipt with background removed]

Is this possible with Sharp, Jimp, ImageMagik or something else? If it is possible with one of these libraries, which would be best applied for this use case?

Comment: All of those tools you mention are just that, tools. They can crop, resize, combine images, adjust levels, etc. But the task you're describing of finding the receipt in the image and cropping to it it outside the scope of one of these libraries. That's typically the kind of code you'd have to write yourself using the library for support.

Comment: Understood. Which library would best suited for this? I don't want to start building with a hand saw if there's a table saw out there that I don't know about. I should clarify the intent of my question.